# i am facing an error to acess the textcontrollers form another .dart file . error: undefined

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Undo feature
i have tried to implement an "undo" feature in a project. To achieve this, I need access to the text controllers from another file. Despite trying numerous solutions suggested on YouTube and by OpenAI, none have been successful. I've even attempted changing the names of the text controllers and re-importing the path, but to no avail.

Comment: are you using setState((){}) or anything similar,
Just put some code it will be helpful t evaluate.

Comment: Add more context to the question. Some code sample and process/what you have done would be helpful.